# can't get data from MySQL by spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have spring web app and I can only get data if I inserted by app.
I can't get data inserted by MySQL workbench user panel.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM  shop WHERE CONCAT( s.name, ' ', s.product, ' ', s.price, ' ', s.adress) LIKE %?1%")
public List<shop> search(String keyword);
```

```
public List<shop> listAll(String keyword) {
    if (keyword != null) {
        return shop_repo.search(keyword);
    }
    shop_repo.findAll();
}
```

For example, i insert  object by workbench user panel

-name=shop

-product=laptops

-price=2000$

-adress=null

When I am typing in the search bar "shop" I cant get anything.

However, when I do inserting by webapp, I can find it then.

Comment: Did you commit in the Workbench?

Comment: @vats Are you committing the data when you are inserting from the MySQL workbench

Comment: yes, i commit it/

Comment: At loading the main table, i can see all inserted data, but when i choose search text and type something about data(for example name) i only can see inserted data by web app